# How to run multiple dos command using WShell.Run

Tags: vbscript, cmd

My use case is to simulate below dos command in vbscript

```
cmd CD C:/
cmd Dir
cmd echo Error Code=%ErrorLevel% >> c:\error.txt
```

I can able to write vbscript code till cmd Dir but don't know how to simulate for error code in a single vbscript code

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "cmd /K CD C:\ & Dir"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put in your commands in a batch file and then run that.

**YourBatch.cmd**

```
CD C:/
Dir
echo Error Code=%ErrorLevel% >> c:\error.txt
```

Then, in your VBscript, call the batch file.

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "YourBatch.cmd"
Set oShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi aphoria, Can't i do this in vbscript?

Comment: Your other is option is to do what you've done and chain the commands using `&` or `&&`.